# Android - clear application data and reboot device

Tags: android, cordova, powermanager

I am programming an Android-application with cordova. This app gets only installed on dedicated Android 5.1.1-devices. Among others I have the functionality to clear all the apps data. I have implemented this functionality in a cordova-plugin:

```
// My Cordova Plugin java
if (action.equals("factory_reset")) {
  try {
    Log.i(TAG, "Factory Reset");
    ((ActivityManager)cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
    rebootDevice();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Error while doing a Factory Reset", ex);
  }
}
```

I want to reboot the device, after the deletion of all app-data is finished. Here is my reboot-function:

```
private void rebootDevice(){
  Context mContext = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
  PowerManager pManager = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  pManager.reboot(null);
}
```

The reboot function itself is working. However I have the problem, that it doesn't reach this function when I call `((ActivityManager)cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();` because the app immediately get's force closed.

How can I solve this? How can I clear the application-data AND reboot the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197546/4742047):

My Plugincode:

```
public boolean execute(final String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
  if (action.equals("factory_reset")) {
    clearApplicationData();
    rebootDevice();
  }
}
```

The private-functions, that are called:

```
private void clearApplicationData() {
  File cache = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
  File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
  Log.d(TAG, "AppDir = " + appDir);
  if (appDir.exists()) {
    String[] children = appDir.list();
    for (String s : children) {
      if (!s.equals("lib")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Delete " + s);
        deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
      }
    }
  }
}

private void rebootDevice(){
  Context mContext = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
  PowerManager pManager = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  pManager.reboot(null);
}
```